# i want to get the first day and last day inside a while loop date and put them in a variable

Tags: php, datetime, while-loop, do-while

i have something like a calendar for praying times,

let us say the calendar from ( 05-12-2020 ) to ( 07-28-2020 )

this calendar have 2 praying times, one in the evening and the other one in the morning, in the begging and ending of the month they are completely different times

***as an example :*** the first pray at ( 01:42 AM ) and the second at ( 00:19 AM )
.. **so no problems with me here.**

but they become at the same time for several days in the middle of this date range

***as an example :*** the first pray becomes ( 01:17 AM ) and the second one also becomes ( 01:17 AM )

**how can i know the date of the first and last day which they became similar and put it in a variable???**

i'm sorry because i really can't explain what i mean very well and the code is also very big so i can't paste it, but i will upload an image to clarify more

**Please notice:** i calculate them through some Mathematical and astronomical equations using the while loop, and the times are different from city to other, so they are dynamic not static but the same situation is happen

i'm thinking for something like that

```
if($first_prayertime == $second_prayertime){
//give me the first and last date they are similar
//and put every one of them in a variable
}
```

[image: the calnder]

Comment: Please provide sample data as `var_export()`. Please show your looped conditional variable declarations with `break`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iterate, check for matching times.

On the first encounter, save both variable with the row's date.

On subsequent matching encounters, overwrite the last date.

As soon as the first date is found AND there is a time mismatch, break the loop to avoid unnecessary iterations.

Pseudo code:

```
$firstPrayerDate = null;
foreach ($prayerData as $row) {
    if ($row['first_prayertime'] === $row['second_prayertime']) {
        if (!$firstPrayerDate) {
            $firstPrayerDate = $row['prayerDate'];
            $lastPrayerDate = $firstPrayerDate
        } else {
            $lastPrayerDate = $row['prayerDate'];
        }
    } elseif ($firstPrayerDate) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your help, and I really apologize for mistakenly deleting the question .. i tried many times through this page and through your profile to give you a reputation but i don't know how because i login with my membership rarely, actually i can't use your exact solution because in my situation i can't break the while loop, but your answer help me to get another idea .. i make 2 different loops, the first one only to get the two dates and store them in an array, and the second one is my main loop for printing and modifying the calendar variables

Comment: This is why it is absolutely vital that you provide a [mcve] so that volunteers can confidently provide a working solution that is ideal for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@mickmackusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943403/mickmackusa) very much for helping me, this is how i solved it

i separated the process into two loops, the first loop to get the dates and store them into array ( then get the first element and the last element of array ), and the second loop is my main big loop to print and modify my calendar variables and functions

i don't know if is it a professional solution or not, but it works anyways and give me what i really need.

```
// prayer calendar for the whole year
$Begin_Date = $Starting_Date = strtotime("2020-01-01");
$Ending_Date = strtotime("2020-12-31");

// My array key number
$Array_Key_Number = 0;
// create a new array
$Days_Date = array();

while($Starting_Date <= $Ending_Date){
      // get the timezone every day to know if is there a daylight saving or not
      $d = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d 12:00:00',$Starting_Date), new DateTimeZone($row->timeZoneId));
      $timeZone = $d->format('P');
      $date = $Starting_Date;
      $PrayerTimes = $PrayingTimes->getPrayerTimes($date, $latitude, $longitude, $timeZone);

      // when the first prayer and second prayer are similar in times...
      // create an array and store the dates in it
      if($PrayerTimes[0] == $PrayerTimes[6]){
          // store every single date in my new array
          $Days_Date[$Array_Key_Number] = date("Y-m-d",$Starting_Date);   
          $Array_Key_Number++;
      }

$Starting_Date = strtotime("+1 day", $Starting_Date);   

}
// first element in array
$First_Date = $Days_Date[0];
// last element in array
$Last_Date  = end($Days_Date);
```